# What is the best way to handle user roles with multiple providers?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, user-roles

Im trying to add user roles into my spring security application(the end goal is to make a role for paid users). Im using oidc for authentication. I have 3 different applications, one client, one resource server and one custom auth server(used to login with username and password). I have also integrated google as login option directly into my client application. [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3qxA.png). Both using authorization code flow.

The problem I encounter is how to integrate user roles the best way. Because Im thinking that all users should be stored at one place.
When users login/registrer with username and password I can get/store the account in the auth server's database. But when someone uses google I have no idea how to store the user.

My questions is:
When someone login with google my client and google are communicating. But is it possible to somehow make my custom auth server act like a "middle man" so I can store and get data, probably from the jwt token? That would be great for implementing my user roles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this "man in the middle" is pretty common. It is called identity federation.

Quite a few OIDC authorization-server on the market support "social login" (login with Google, but also Facebook, Github, etc.) and role management.

Keycloak is a famous "on premise" sample, but there are also many SaaS ones like Okta, Auth0, Amazon Cognito,...